# Connect to database from an App_Code class file

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I was wondering whether or not there was a way of connecting to my local database, where then I can access my tables to run various sql queries, I wanted to do it in a class as I then can then reuse my functions elsewhere and not have duplicate code.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: yes sure, what i want to do is establish a connection to my local database from within a class file.

Comment: So what have you tried to do that?

Comment: I was thinking of using the system.configuration configuration manager to connect, i have already done this on my .aspx  files, is this achievable within a class?